# outlook.com (Exchange ActiveSync) on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, exchange-activesync

Outlook.com offers email/contacts/calendar similar to Google. With my iPhone and iPad (iOS 6.1.3) I can connect to outlook.com by setting up an Exchange account. It uses the Exchange ActiveSync protocol. On OS X Mountain Lion I can choose an Exchange server in the Mail, Contacts & Calendar settings tab, but it does not connect when I put in my outlook.com login.

Is there a way to connect to outlook.com via Exchange ActiveSync to access email, contacts and calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike iOS, the Mail app in OS X does not currently support Exchange ActiveSync.

Exchange ActiveSync is different from the standard Exchange format. A mail client that supports Exchange may not support EAS.

Comment: True, it's not working ... :)

Comment: For Apple to support Exchange ActiveSync on iOS but not on Mac OS is a giant WTF.